# Is taproot considered nonstandard to older clients?

Tags: bitcoind, mempool, taproot, p2tr

When asking an older bitcoind node to broadcast a transaction which includes or spends a p2tr output, how will they respond? Will they broadcast the transaction? Will only certain bitcoind versions broadcast them? Which ones if that's the case?

I'm not asking if it's possible to detect if a user's bitcoind node will broadcast the p2tr transaction, which can be accomplished with `getblockchaininfo` checking the bip9 version bits supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P2TR **outputs** (and higher-version native witness outputs) are standard since Bitcoin Core v0.19: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15846

Inputs **spending** P2TR outputs are non-standard in all Bitcoin Core versions since 2012 or so, except those versions that have BIP341 [implemented](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20165) for which they're standard since Taproot activation. The first version implementing BIP341 was Bitcoin Core v0.21.1.